# Parsing a JSON representation of an xml file

Tags: java, json, xml, rest

So I am getting information from a RESTful API, in the form of a JSON object.

However, on the page I am accessing, there is an xml file. (POM.xml to be precise)
I need to parse the `<groupID>`, `<artifactId>` and `<version>` info from each `<dependency>` from this xml file. There are on the order of around 1000 dependencies I will need to retrieve.

But when I look at the the JSON array of this xml file I get this:

```
{
    "lines": [
        {
            "text": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
        },
        {
            "text": "<project xmlns=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd\">"
        },
        {
            "text": "    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>"
        },
        {
            "text": "    <groupId>insertGroupHere</groupId>"
        },
        {
            "text": "    <artifactId>GenericApplication</artifactId>"
        },
        {
            "text": "    <version>1.1.7</version>"
        },
        {
            "text": "    <packaging>jar</packaging>"
        },
        {
            "text": "    <dependencies>"
        },
        {
            "text": "        <dependency>"
        },
        {
            "text": "            <groupId>junit</groupId>"
        },
        {
            "text": "            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>"
        },
        {
            "text": "            <version>4.12</version>"
        },
        {
            "text": "            <scope>test</scope>"
        },
        {
            "text": "        </dependency>"
        },
... etc
... etc
... etc
```

In lieu of going through each "text" name, and checking its key to see if it equals `<dependency>` Is there a smarter way of doing this? I have not found any libraries which can help. Whilst there are numerous libraries out there that will convert JSON to XML and back again, I don't think they would work in this case.

I would like to know if there are any libraries (or even sneaky tricks) which can quickly deal with information in this form, without having to re-invent the wheel.

[Also, if you feel something is wrong about this question,  I would prefer if you were to tell me what was incorrect, before down-voting so I get a chance to improve and learn.]

Thanks

Comment: Concatenate all the lines into a single string, then paste iT as XML, then extract the information that you want. It’s the only guaranteed way. You can’t assume that any information you need is on a single line (it could be spread over multiple) or that each line only contains one piece of information. The format you receive is pretty useless, except perhaps for very simple text editors.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Hmm. That is a good idea. I suppose that it is cleaner and faster then checking all of the individual `"text"` names, for the info we want. I will leave the question for a while, and see if anyone else has any clever ideas.

Comment: This looks like someone was told "JSON is more fashionable than XML these days, we ought to deliver results in JSON", so they did so, without caring whether the JSON format they chose was actually any use to anyone.